# Removing unnecessary white-space

Tags: javascript, html, css, whitespace

I have this fragment class which marks an area with red. My system is separated into two types: categories and rules. When rules are fragmented, they receive the new css class well and it looks properly, but it's different with categories, they have that unnecessary white-space in top of the category.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: the unnecessary whitespace]

Here is a live demo and you can check the source code for more information as I wont be able to provide the proper code since I am not the original author of the style:

http://zirotec-uka.com/dugi/phpBB3/rules.php#rule1

Thank you.

Comment: don't think the javascript tag is relevant to this question.

Comment: @jbabey, well, it implies that answer can be javascript based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rule specifying `h3 { margin-top: 20px; }`. That is what causes the space.

You can override that with `#main h3 { margin-top: 0; }`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

`#main ul h3, #main ol h3 { margin-top: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the "padding" CSS element.

You can do this statically as follows:

```
$("#rule1").css("padding-top", "0px");
```

See how it looks now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3rR.jpg

Comment: Why to use javascript when is not necessary?

Comment: @Caelea because OP tagged his question as JS, I assumed he did not have control of his CSS.  I fail to see how this answer deserves downvotes.

Comment: First, it doesn't need jQuery to be fixed, nor JavaScript itself. Plus, it's not the padding, but margin (that of `h3`) that is causing the issue. And *"padding" CSS element* is wrong, it's **property**! Anyway, removing `padding` from `#rules` would not fix the issue.

Comment: @psycketom I just did that, and it did solve the problem.  Take a look at my screenshot.  This same strategy could be used in CSS.

Comment: I took a look at your screenshot, but while it solves the issue, it spawns a whole set of new ones. The `padding` of `.fragment` gets removed also, but it's intentional.

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by a the padding in .fragment (style.php:4007)

```
.fragment {
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    background-color: #ECD5D8;
    color: #BC2A4D;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You need to change this or override it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the default padding set by the browser, and can be solve by following rule

`#rules li{ padding:0px;}`